# Search for a string name inside object with spaces

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, ecmascript-6

I have an object like this which contain a string name with whitespaces :

```
{
 xxx: "/xxx/",
 name: "string with spaces",
 items: {
  method: "GET",
 }
}
```

I search inside my request query for the name in order to get the item object of it, like this :

```
http://localhost:3000?$name=test
```

But how should i now search for a string with whitespaces like this :

```
http://localhost:3000?$name=string with spaces
```

Here is the process of how things work :

if i do not specify a name in the query like this `http://localhost:3000?$name=`, i get the following :

```
[
 {
  name: "admin",
  item: [xxx]
 },
 {
  name: "auth",
  item: [xxx]
 }
]
```

If i specify for example the object with the name `admin` like this : `http://localhost:3000?$name=admin`, then i'll get the following :

```
[
 {
  name: "manage users",
  items: {}
 },
 {
  name: "Get user`",
  items: {}
 }
]
```

Now what i'm trying to do is to add in the query the name with the whitespaces like this : `http://localhost:3000?$name=admin/manage users` so that i can retrieve its items as well.

When i try the following code :

```
  const { $name } = req.query;

  const name = $name.split('/');
  let currentItem = req.doc;

  name.forEach((name) => {
    const decoded = decodeURIComponent(name);
    currentItem.forEach((entry) => { 
      if (entry.name === decoded) {
        currentItem = entry.item; 
      }
    });
  });
```

Everything works fine if there is no whitespaces but once i search for something with whitespaces then `i get undefined for the entry.item` but once i console log on the entry then i get the name entered decoded .

Comment: the parameter will be uri encoded, so do an uri decode and then search the name

Comment: when i console log on the name retrieved from the query, i get it as i really want like this [ 'admin', 'Remove user' ] but the page won't show anything once the url contain whitespaces

Comment: it's true it's an encoded uri like this ?$name=admin/Remove%20user

Comment: can you include an example of what is the input and what is your expected output? I don't  get the part "but the page won't show anything once the URL contain whitespaces"

Comment: the issue is URI encoding as others have mentioned. you cannot use spaces in the web browser's search bar, so the browser translates spaces (and other characters) into other characters.

Comment: just updated my code

Answer (score 2):

It'll be URI encoded - use `decodeURIComponent` to get what you want:

```js
const encoded = encodeURIComponent("string with spaces");
const decoded = decodeURIComponent(encoded);
console.log(encoded);
console.log(decoded);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```